# How to set cider using boot middle ware?

Tags: clojure, cider

In Emacs with `cider` and `lein` installed, I can `M-x cider-jack-in` to start clojure repl. I installed `boot` and would like to switch from `lein` to `boot`. How to set `cider` to use `boot` middle ware?

(I don't want to remove leiningen right now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First follow these instructions [on the Readme](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider#using-boot) so that boot knows about CIDER.

> Boot users can configure the tool to include the middleware automatically in all of their projects using a `~/.boot/profile.boot` file like so:

```
(require 'boot.repl)

(swap! boot.repl/*default-dependencies*
       concat '[[cider/cider-nrepl "0.9.1"]])

(swap! boot.repl/*default-middleware*
       conj 'cider.nrepl/cider-middleware)
```

Then just invoke `cider-jack-in` on a project that contains a
`build.boot` file. If this project also has a `project.clj` file, CIDER
will ask you whether you want boot or lein.

Comment: Create an empty `build.boot` file in `~/` dir, then each time `emacs` is started, `cider-jack-in` works.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to post an updated version for the answer. You can find all the necessary info about Boot CIDER repl setup here https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Cider-REPL . It provides multiple ways to set it up.

An important thing to note is boot parameters setup. To make Cider behave as expected.

`(setq cider-boot-parameters "repl -s wait")`

Also each project in boot tends to have `build.boot` file, that serve similar purpose as `project.clj`

The easiest way to transition is to read https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Boot-for-Leiningen-Users , https://juxt.pro/blog/posts/boot-parity.html and try to build a small toy application.

Answer (score 0):

Use cider-connect instead of cider-jack-in

Comment: Welcome to emacs.stackexchange! Can you please expand your answer in a way that a user (not necessary just the original question poster) looking for an answer gets adequate amount of information all inclusive in your answer?

Comment: Since this answer popped up in the evaluation for "low quality answer", I'll comment: there is nothing wrong with answering in a short and concise manner. More so, if it can be answered briefly, then please do. To quote Bill Gates who (allegedly) said that judging the larger program is better is like judging the heavier plane is better, which I'd extend to the length of answers as well.